# How to add some custom text on action area on admin side

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, admin, grid, uicomponent

From the image given below how can i add a **text** in that area.

I have created the listing page using `ui components`

```
 <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">order_edit.order_items</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">order_edit.order_items</item>
    </item>
    <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">spinner_columns</item>
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="back" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">back</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Back</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">action-default scalable back</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/index</item>
        </item>
        <item name="update" xsi:type="string">Company\mModule\Block\Adminhtml\Orders\Edit\Button\Send</item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you update your code?

Comment: No please check the question.

Comment: Now please check my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set a text here with ui_components because this emplacement is reserved for store switcher. See screenshot below:

[image]

But you can add a title to the page in your controller /Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Action/Index.php in execute methode:

```
/**
     * Index action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->setActiveMenu('Ultranoir_FAQ::question');
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Question'));

        return $resultPage;
    }
```

Comment: Ok. Your answer didn't solved my problem but gave me an alternate  solution. 
Is there a way to change the title size?

Comment: You can do it in css if you create a custom admin theme but I dont think you can do it in controller. If you want to do it in css, create an admin theme and you can use the body class and title class to select the title.